# Should I be worried about this strange notification from Delta?

Tags: notifications, security

I got a notification from the `Fly Delta` app that just says "test". The icon appears to be missing. Should I be concerned about this? I've uninstalled the Delta app, but I'm unsure if I need to do more.

This is, to the best of my knowledge, the official Delta Airlines app installed from the Play Store.

[image]

Comment: This might just be some Delta engineer trying something out, and maybe mistakenly pushing it to customer devices, but I don't know how to find out if it is legitimate testing or a potential sign of some exploit.

Answer (score 2):

A [Twitter search](https://twitter.com/search?q=delta%20test&src=typed_query) suggests that a lot of people got the same message. It appears to be an error at Delta. What I don't know is whether there's any way to confirm that a particular message came from the app vs spoofed it in some way.

Comment: It's possible to check the sender by using a built-in/3rd-party notification log.